# I'm trying to use the abline function but it's giving me errors

Tags: r

```
ill <- read.csv("/Applications/therbook/Illiteracy.csv", header =TRUE)
attach(ill)
names(ill) 
head(ill) 
tail(ill)
```

I observed that when the *illit* rate went above 50 the *births* per woman were higher with 4 and higher of birth of children

```
# Observing the graph it's clearly shown how illiteracy affects birth rates in country.
# The more a woman is illiterate, the more children she bares
plot(Births,Illit) 

regression_coe <- lm(Births~Illit,data=ill) 
regression_coe
```

in our case the coefficient will be 0.05452

```
plot(ill$Births,ill$Illit)
abline(regression_coe)
```

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...):plot.new has not been called yet

```
r <- cor(Births,Illit)
r^2
```

Therefore about 59% is explained in this linear regression

```
rr <- resid(regression_coe)
plot(Births,Illit)
abline(rr)
```

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...):plot.new has not been called yet

Comment: Note that `abline` ([docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html)) is for a straight line according to user preferences, ie. it expects you to input slope and intersection rather than a collection of numbers. Those you can fit into the usual `plot` command.

Answer (score 0):

The residuals are a long named vector and abline cannot take this as an input. `abline` can take in a slope and intercept, values to make vertical or horizontal lines, coefficients, or a linear model object. If you're looking for patterns in the residuals you may want to do:

```
   plot(resid(regression_coe))
   abline(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Question, comment, and answer point in the direction of `abline()`but the problem seems to be associated with the use of `lm()`.

The following pieces of code work for me:

```
regression_coe <- lm(Illit ~ Births, data = ill) 
regression_coe
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = Illit ~ Births, data = ill)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)       Births  
#      -8.24        10.84  

plot(ill$Births, ill$Illit)
abline(regression_coe)
```

Note that the OP has `regression_coe <- lm(Births~Illit,data=ill)`.

[image]

```
resid(regression_coe)
```

[image]

```
regression_coe <- lm(Births ~ Illit, data = ill)
regression_coe
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = Births ~ Illit, data = ill)
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)        Illit  
#    1.94874      0.05452 

plot(ill$Illit, ill$Births)
abline(regression_coe)
```

[image]

#### Data

```
ill <- structure(list(ID = 1:94, Country = structure(1:94, .Label = c("Albania", 
"Algeria", "Bahrain", "Belize", "Benin", "Bolivia", "Botswana", 
"Brazil", "Brunei", "Burkina Faso", "Burma", "Burundi", "Cambodia", 
"Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "China", "Colombia", 
"Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic of the", "Congo, Republic of the", 
"Cote d'Ivoire", "Djibouti", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", 
"Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", 
"Fiji", "Gambia, The", "Ghana", "Guatemala", "Guinea-Bissau", 
"Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", 
"Israel", "Jamaica", "Jordan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Laos", "Lebanon", 
"Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
"Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", 
"Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Oman", 
"Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", 
"Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Rwanda", "Saudi Arabia", 
"Senegal", "Singapore", "South Africa", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", 
"Swaziland", "Syria", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tunisia", 
"Turkey", "United Arab Emirates", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), Illit = c(20.5, 39.1, 
15, 5.9, 73.5, 18.5, 17.6, 11.9, 11.5, 83.4, 18.1, 54.8, 39.8, 
30.9, 60.1, 60.7, 19.6, 7.5, 50.7, 44.9, 21.6, 59.1, 41.6, 15.2, 
9.1, 53.1, 22.3, 21.6, 52.4, 64.8, 8.1, 66.9, 32.7, 36.8, 72.4, 
48.8, 23, 9.5, 51.7, 15.9, 27.4, 6.2, 8.3, 13.4, 20.3, 18.3, 
43.4, 17.8, 5.5, 59.5, 28.1, 8, 37.5, 50.3, 14.7, 82, 6.4, 68.1, 
17.4, 9.8, 67.3, 16.3, 32.2, 90.2, 39, 32.8, 69.4, 8.1, 40.6, 
7, 13.3, 8.8, 5.5, 15, 35.2, 29.3, 69.2, 10.4, 14.3, 10.1, 49.5, 
19.2, 36.1, 29.4, 5.4, 53.1, 35.6, 21.4, 18.5, 6.9, 8.5, 69.8, 
25.2, 12.9), Births = c(1.78, 2.44, 2.34, 2.97, 5.6, 3.65, 3.03, 
2.29, 2.38, 5.9, 2.23, 6.8, 3.89, 3.53, 4.73, 6.3, 1.81, 2.4, 
3.76, 6.7, 5.6, 4.7, 4.74, 2.73, 2.67, 3.1, 2.76, 5.89, 5.24, 
5.32, 2.79, 4.4, 4.06, 4.33, 7.08, 3.75, 3.47, 0.97, 2.84, 2.27, 
2.07, 2.82, 2.38, 3.29, 4.98, 2.39, 4.5, 2.25, 3.4, 6.78, 2.85, 
0.88, 5.04, 5.84, 2.74, 6.72, 1.37, 5.59, 1.98, 2.11, 5.3, 3.66, 
3.08, 7.67, 5.5, 3.44, 4.12, 2.62, 3.8, 3.67, 2.74, 1.4, 1.8, 
2.89, 5.8, 3.83, 4.9, 1.24, 2.78, 1.91, 4.15, 3.91, 3.24, 5.2, 
1.89, 5.03, 2.04, 2.19, 2.43, 2.65, 1.78, 5.87, 5.4, 3.34)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Country", "Illit", "Births"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-94L))
```